# Identify terminated Akka Stream stage

Tags: akka, akka-stream

When the ActorSystem terminates I get the message below.

> GraphStage
> [akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphStages$IgnoreSink$$anon$10@57026716]
> terminated abruptly, caused by for example materializer or actor
> system termination.

How would I go debugging this so that I can identify the exact component instance ?
I am also using some libs that themselves use Akka Stream components that I use in my stream. (akka-stream-kafka)

Comment: have you tried using logging techniques? https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/log.html

Comment: If you're terminating your `ActorSystem`, all of your streams will stop, so it doesn't really matter which component(s) of those streams terminate first, does it?

Comment: If you're asking "how can I prevent this and do a more graceful shutdown?", you would most likely add a `KillSwitch` to the streams and arrange to call the `shutdown` method on the `KillSwitch`(es) before terminating the `ActorSystem`.  You might not be able to add a `KillSwitch` to library usages of Akka Streams, but such libraries not supporting a graceful shutdown may be an indication that abrupt termination isn't a problem for them.

Comment: @LeviRamsey indeed, using a KillSwitch is probably the best solution. In my case i was already using a KillSwitch but the Complete/Cancel signals were not properly propagating. Now I fixed it, but I am still interested in this question of identifying these components.